# error in webengine of javafx when using apostrophe in combination with some javascript

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webengine

i wrote a little wrapperapplication for an oldschool html4 webchat (so i can send custom messages when someone joins etc.). but i am facing some trouble when i'd like to update the main view.

my unit test (to not annoy the guys in the chat) is this:

```
package chatclient.gui;

import chatclient.entities.Message;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.ApplicationExtension;
import org.testfx.framework.junit5.Start;



@ExtendWith(ApplicationExtension.class)
class FXApplicationTest {


    FXApplication sut;

    private final String killedString = """
            <table border=0><tr><td valign=bottom><FONT SIZE=-2>(13:48)</FONT> <b><font title="myself"><span onclick="fluester('myself')">
            <b><FONT COLOR="#000000">s</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">l</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">a</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">c</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">k</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">i</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">t</FONT>
            <FONT COLOR="#000000">o</FONT></b></span></b>: <span onclick="javascript: repClick('myself')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="/synapse/replacer/myself.jpg" alt="&#58;myself"></span></font></td></tr></table>
            """;
    private final String killedString2 = "<table>hi</table>";

    private final String initString = """
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="de">
            <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/someroom/style_stream.css?1692439165">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                doscroll = true;
                parent.forces = false;
                function Scroller() {
                 if (parent.force) { doscroll = true }
                  if (doscroll != false) {
                    window.scrollBy(0,50);
                  }
                  window.setTimeout("Scroller()", 50);
                }
                Scroller();
                parent.atok = 'UuXaM';
                function atok(p1) {
                  parent.atok = p1;
                }
                        
                window.status="powered by www.somedomain.de";
                        
                window.onmouseover=function(e){doscroll=false;};\s
                window.onmouseout=function(e){doscroll=true;}
                
                function wopen(link,wi,he) {
                      wincom = window.open(link ,"fenster","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,width="+wi+",height="+he);
                      wincom.focus() ;
                }
                
                function repClick(rep) {
                  parent.info.document.eingabe.message.value+=':' + rep;
                  parent.info.document.eingabe.message.focus();
                  return false;
                }
                        
                function CallPrem() {
                  window.open("/someroom/premium/myself/","Prem","scrollbars=no,width=205,height=260,resizable=no,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,location=no");
                }
                        
                function fluester(fchatter) {
                      parent.info.document.eingabe.message.value="/f "+fchatter+" ";
                      parent.info.document.eingabe.message.focus();
                      var pos = parent.info.document.eingabe.message.createTextRange();
                      pos.collapse(false);
                      pos.select();
                      return false;
                }
                        
                function team() {
                      parent.info.document.eingabe.message.value="/team ";
                      parent.info.document.eingabe.message.focus();
                      var pos = parent.info.document.eingabe.message.createTextRange();
                      pos.collapse(false);
                      pos.select();
                      return false;
                }
                
                parent.clearTimeout(parent.cdProbmodus);
                parent.clearTimeout(parent.cdProbmodusRC);
                
                function LoginSound() {
                    if (parent.forces) {
                     ausgabe = '<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="/8.wav" type="audio/wav"/></audio>';
                        document.getElementById('soundcontainer').innerHTML=ausgabe;
                    }
                }
                        
              setTimeout('parent.info.sende();', 1000);
              setTimeout('parent.info.sendes();', 1000);
                
            </script>
            </head>
            <body onFocus="doscroll=false" onMouseOver="doscroll=false">
            powered by <a href="https://www.somedomain.de" target="_blank">https://www.somedomain.de</a>
            <hr>
            <script language="JavaScript">parent.rightFrame.document.location="/cgi-bin/ol.cgi?cid=someroom&raum=main";</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/grundscripts.js"></script><script language="javascript">linkCnt=0; tds=document.getElementsByTagName("td"); function autoLink(){for(;linkCnt<tds.length;linkCnt++){ if(tds[linkCnt].innerHTML.match(/([^"'=]+(?:http|ftp|https):\\/\\/[^<>\\s']+)/i)){tds[linkCnt].innerHTML=tds[linkCnt].innerHTML.replace(/([^"'=]+)((?:http|ftp|https):\\/\\/[^<>\\s']+)/i, "$1<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$2</a>");}else{ tds[linkCnt].innerHTML=tds[linkCnt].innerHTML.replace(/([^"'=\\/\\w\\.]+)(\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\.\\w\\w+[^<>\\s']*)/i, "$1<a href='http:\\/\\/$2' target='_blank'>$2</a>");}}}window.setInterval("autoLink()", 500)</script><br><style type=text/css>font[color=red]{color:#ae0aa8}</style><br><br>Willkommen <b><FONT COLOR="#000000">s</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">l</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">a</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">c</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">k</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">i</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">t</FONT><FONT COLOR="#000000">o</FONT></b>. <span onclick="javascript: repClick('huhu')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://server4.somedomain.de/someroom/replacer/huhu.gif" alt="&#58;huhu"></span> Viel Freude beim chatten. <br><ul><li>Bei Problemen im Chat bitte wenden an: user2old (vorher user1) <span onclick="javascript: repClick('user2old')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://server4.somedomain.de/someroom/replacer/user2old.gif" alt="&#58;user2old"></span> user1lein@web.de,<br> oder an user2 <span onclick="javascript: repClick('hase')" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="https://server4.somedomain.de/someroom/replacer/hase.gif" alt="&#58;hase"></span> haseprof@gmail.com.<br>Bitte die Mail-Adressen für eventuelle Notfälle <u>speichern</u> (z.B. Ausfall der Chatsoftware).</li><br><li>Wenn irgendetwas im Chat dauerhaft stört, bitte ich euch, konstruktive Kritik nicht zurückzuhalten, damit nach Lösungen gesucht werden kann.</li><br></ul>
            <script>function appendText(extraStr) {document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML + extraStr;}</script>
            """;

    @Start
    private void start(Stage stage) {
        sut = new FXApplication();
        sut.init(initString);
    }

    @Test
    void can_init() {
        sut.append(new Message(killedString2, "ourself"));
    }
}
```

when i use killedString, i get a big exception. when i use killedString2 it works.
i am 100% sure this is because of " and ' - when i replace them i lose the html information, but it works. anyone an idea how i can use the " and ' in the webengine too?

the exception is this:

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'myself'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:160)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1576)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:985)
    at chatclient.gui.FXApplication.lambda$append$12(FXApplication.java:223)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
> Task :test
```

the code i use to actually send the message is this:

```
    runInFxThread(() -> {

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Appending cleaned string:");
                        webView.getEngine().executeScript("appendText(\"" + s.getCleanedForEngine() + "\");");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("EXCEPTION APPEARED AT: " + s.getRawString());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    webView.getEngine().executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
                }
```

anyone an idea how to correctly escape those chars without losing html stuff?

Comment: See the [escaping section for this JavaScript tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript#escaping-quotes-and-apostrophes-in-strings).  Perhaps the template escaping method described there using back ticks will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working with replacing the following chars:

```
message.replace("\n", "\\n")
       .replace("\r", "\\n")
       .replace("\"", "\\\"");
```